# Beeping Alarm Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an alarm function with Python3. The below code does work but it doesn't seem like this is the most optimal way of achieving something like this. Is there a more pythonic way?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import time

def alarm():
    os.system('amixer -D pulse sset Master 30%')     # >> Set initial volume
    for beep in range(0, 20):
        time.sleep(.002)
        os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % (.08, 2500))

alarm()
```

Comment: Welcome to Codereview, Kryptos.

Answer (score 6):

- **Pythonic approach**

  For sound playback in Python, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python).
- **Avoid `os.system`**

  If you are forced to use it, supply a fully qualified path to the executable. You never know what weird program called `play` may be in the search path prior to an intended one.
- **Modularize**

  As written, the code is not reusable. An attempt to `import` it would result in an immediate alarm sound. Put the call to `alarm` in an

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
  ```

  clause.
- **Avoid magic numbers**

  All the parameters (beep duration, volume, etc) better be passed via a command line (see `sys.argv` and `optparse` module).
- **Dummy variable**

  is customarily denoted as `_`:

  ```
      for _ in range(20):
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of formatting strings:

```
'play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % (.08, 2500)
```

The current Python method is to use `str.format`.

```
'play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth {} sine {}'.format(.08, 2500)
```

It's not a huge advantage here, though you'll notice it's type agnostic. But it has many advantages available so it's good to get used to using it.